# Calculating rotation matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation

I am writing a script verifying the properties of rotation matrix.I am making a call to the rotation function that I have written for making the rotation matrix... Is there any matlab command to construct the rotation matrix directly.
I have used the following formula in the function to calculate rotation matrix:

```
R = I + sin(fi) * skew(k) + (1-cos(fi))* skew-square(k)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Your formula should give you the correct rotation matrix. Are you just looking for something to verify your results, or are you having difficulty applying the formula for different rotations?

Answer (score 0):

rotx, roty, rotz exist in Phased Array System Toolbox http://www.mathworks.nl/help/phased/motion-modeling-and-coordinate-systems.html?searchHighlight=rotx , no specific function in Matlab.